# IntelliJ Idea VCS shows three files

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, pull, merge-conflict-resolution

Hi when I click on Intellij Idea's VCS code it shows me diff between three files - one with SHA1 hash , other the base version and third the server version. Please explain what do they refer too.I want to keep other users' changes and merge my change.We are using git as VCS. This problem comes when I try to take a pull.It says :

```
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

If it helps I can post output of git diff command.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a merge conflict. You're going to want to resolve it (and that is strictly dependent on what code you're dealing with and how **you** have to approach it).

Comment: I want to keep other users' changes as well as merge my changes.The confusion is how do I do the merge.The files are in read mode.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is letting you know you have unmerged files. If you would like to keep other people's changes, assuming they are on the master branch or another development branch:

1. Create your own local branch for your changes
2. `git add` your changes to your branch
3. merge your branch with the branch you would like to join. Be aware this may require resolving some conflicts. See the documentation on `git-merge` "[How To Resolve Conflicts](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts)" for further guidance. If you are using Intellij, instructions for merging can be found on their [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html#d173763e19).

> **To merge a branch**
>
> Invoke the Branches menu as described in Accessing Git Branches Popup
>   Menu. Select a branch in the pop-up list that shows all available
>   local and remote branches, and choose Merge from the submenu. The
>   selected branch will be merged into the branch that is currently
>   checked out. If there are merge conflicts, you will be prompted to
>   resolve them.
>
> If your local changes are going to be overwritten by merge, IntelliJ
>   IDEA suggests to perform smart merge (similar to smart checkout.

For more information check out the online version of [Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) book.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need to know how to I do the 3rd step ?

Comment: Merging files in git can be tricky. You can perform the merge via command line, or GIT-GUI or an IDE. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the started merge of the files.
So to fix the issue you need to merge diffs properly.
Some files were changed and they contain unproper symbols, like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
open an issue
=======
ask your question in IRC.
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

This means that there is a conflict there.

In order to resolve it you can manually edit these files.

The next option can be applied if there was no local changes before the update. In such case you can revert changes and to try update project again.

SHA-1 tab means your changes, middle tab represents merge result, and the last one (Server changes) means update from the remote.